# OnActionExecuted being called unexpectedly

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following action method:

```
        public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            [ProfileAction]
            [CustomAction]
            public string FilterTest()
            {
                //Does not get executed
                return "This is the FilterTest action";
            }
        }
```

Here's the code for the filters:

```
public class CustomActionAttribute : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //This is executed first
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        //This is executed third
    }
}

public class ProfileActionAttribute : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //This is executed second
        filterContext.Result = new HttpNotFoundResult();
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        //this does not execute
    }
}
```

According to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs) the `OnActionExecuted()` is executed after a controller action is executed.

The action method `FilterTest()` is never called because I set the Result property in `ProfileActionAttribute.OnActionExecuting()`.
Why does CustomActionAttribute.OnActionExecuted() get called if the action method never even gets called?

Comment: I think it's because really the action _did_ get called. The client requested the URL associated with the action method, it was routed to that action, and then the requested attribute filters kicked things off. You just returned the result before it got to the main method, that's all. Think of the attributes as extensions to that method, they are still part of the process of executing the action associated with the URL that the user called.

Comment: @ADyson If the action method did get executed, then why does ProfileActionAttribute.OnActionExecuted() not get called?

Comment: I don't know for sure, sorry. Maybe because you had set the result in the same filter. It would be interesting to know what happens if you switch the order of execution of the attributes (done using the Order parameter in the attribute declaration). ASP.NET MVC is open-source, you can always go and see for yourself exactly what the logic is. This article might also be relevant or at least provide context. https://gregshackles.com/custom-ordering-of-action-filters-in-asp-net-mvc/